# How Do I PERMANENTLY HIDE/REMOVE the navigation bar in my first View Controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

hey guys I'm currently having a dilemma regarding the nav bar in my 1st view controller scene. i hid it well with:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = True
```

under the ViewDidLoad not knowing this was only a temporary fix. every time the back button is pushed in my second view controller scene to return to the home controller scene, the nav bar pops up again! HELP!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a code example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try viewWillAppear, which will be called every time a view is about to appear. The function you are using, viewDidLoad, can run more than once, but usually only runs once per application session.

Comment: func viewDidAppear() {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        
        } in this form? i just tried to apply it and it didn't work :(

Comment: Make sure to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` when you override viewWillAppear. Otherwise I think that code should work.

Comment: Whoops now I see you mentioned `viewDidAppear` I think it is better to use `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 2):

Move that line of code to the `viewWillAppear` method.

I don't know the Swift equivalent but put this in viewWillAppear:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]
```

Comment: func viewDidAppear() {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        
        } in this form? it didn't work :(

Comment: @RobertTillman check out my edit - not sure of the Swift equivalent code